# Does Page loading Stops when an async controller have Method that await and still loading data from database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a async controller in my asp.net MVC web application. In controller there is a method that loads data from database, and I await that method by adding "await" keyword as prefix. Now My question is if I have big amount of data to load through that await method, does page loading will stop or page continue to load until method return data. If it will stop then how it will show returned data. Thanks.

Comment: With await, page loading won't stop or continue, page loading will wait.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by page loading?

Answer (score 1):

If, when you say "continue to load", you mean "continue to wait", then yes. The browser will continue to wait.

The browser will have no idea what's going on. To the browser, this is what happens:

1. It makes the request.
2. It waits.
3. It gets data back.

The browser doesn't know what the server is doing during the time it's waiting.

Using `async`/`await` doesn't change that. If it awaits a database request, then it will not return any data to the browser until the database returns the data.